# How to make a script to be able to access only some files?

Tags: files, permissions

Let's say I have a script `remove.sh`

```
rm -r "$1"
```

I want this script to be able to remove things only inside the folder `~/Desktop/A` and nowhere else.

So, when I run `./remove.sh ~/Desktop/A/file1` it should be successful, but, when I run `./remove.sh ~/.bashrc`, it should be failed.

The purpose of this question is to prevent some random scripts to do something dangerous such as remove something in my home directory.

Comment: Note: using filename extensions is bad practice. e.g. When you re-write it in python/C/go/awk/etc, you will have to edit every script that calls this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how UNIX file permissions are meant to work: privileges are given to users (or groups of users), not individual programs (makes sense, because otherwise all you need to do is copy the program, but not its restrictions).

So, what you want to do would be possible using a detour through making a new user, as which you can run that program, who you give (using either classic UNIX owner/group rights, or ACLs) rights to the folder (and not much else).

But honestly, you're solving something backwards: whatever starts the script as this different user could again circumvent the ban by just not starting it as that user.

You could write a SELinux module to prohibit unlinking of anything not having a specific SELinux context, but, um, that's complicated and for the exact same reasons as above easy to circumvent.

So, "making unable to..." will not work if the user starting the program *has* the privilege to delete things. Whatever problem you're solving, you might need to look at a fundamentally different architecture for it!

Comment: I think you might be right, changing permission is not the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm_selectively()
{
  local path="$1"
  local st=1
  if [[ $path == ~/Desktop/A ]]; then
    rm -r "$path"
    st=$?
  else
    printf '%s\n' "You are trying to remove something else"
  fi
  return $st
}

main()
{
  if (($# < 1)); then 
    printf '%s\n' "You need to provide a path"
  else
  rm_selectively "$1"
  fi
}
main "$1"
```

Make it executable (don't add any `.sh` to your script please) and run it

Answer (score 0):

You could include a test in the script so that it will run only if the resolved path parameter is contained in `~/desktop/A`:

```bsh
realpath "$1" | grep -q '^'"$HOME"'/Desktop/A/' || exit 1
rm -r "$1"
```